# Custom ActionMapper in struts2

Tags: struts2

The issue I am facing has to do with the method `handleSpecialParameters()` inside `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.DefaultActionMapper` class.

The problem is that the `actionName` should be `"nameOfActionID"` for example `"name139"`.

But inside `handleSpecialParameters()` this name is changed and there is a 0 that is added at the end of the name ("name0"). That's why I have tried to create my own custom action mapper in order to skip this method.

Does anybody know how I can configure my `struts.xml` to use this custom action mapper?

I have seen the [custom ActionMapper link](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/action-mapper.html#custom-actionmapper) but I got an error due to -bean when I started the server.

The application uses struts2 2.3.37

Comment: What is the actual error you got? "-bean" isn't much to go on.

Comment: If you don't want to use special parameters then you can turn off DMI. What is the reason to use a custom action mapper? Where's the code?